How to add a custom domain for preview in vercel using Azure pipeline
I am having my project in Azure Repo and i want to deploy my project in Vercel which i have done using the below pipeline.In that repo i am having the develop branch which i want to use for the preview for this i want to add a custom domain as well in the azure pipeline. Because in Vercel i have already added a domain for the production (main branch).
Since i am not using Github it is bit diffcult for me to set the develop branch as preview and add a custom domain.
When the below pipeline code run in the Azure pipeline the build fails at the same time on vercel the deployment seems successful but i can't add my custom domain from pipeline.
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: deploy_main
  displayName: Deploy to Production
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'))
  steps:
  - task: vercel-deployment-task@1
    inputs:
      vercelProjectId: ''
      vercelOrgId: ''
      vercelToken: $(VERCEL_TOKEN)
      production: true

- job: deploy_develop
  displayName: Deploy to Preview
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'))
  steps:
  - task: vercel-deployment-task@1
    inputs:
      vercelProjectId: ''
      vercelOrgId: ''
      vercelToken: $(VERCEL_TOKEN)
      production: false
      previewDomain: 'domainname.co'



I faced the same problem and couldn't find a way to add the domain using the DevOps task.
The workaround I did was to use vercel alias set [deployment-url] [custom-domain].
So after deployment with production: false is done, I just run the alias command in my terminal and it worked. https://vercel.com/docs/cli/alias.
Make sure to login to Vercel in your terminal first and not to add any protocol to the [custom-domain].
 Let me know if you found a better way.
i.e. vercel alias set https://random-domain.vercel.app mypreview.website.com
Yeah, you have to run this command after each preview deployment.
